# dynamic url using express.js confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
router.get('/:username', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('dashboard');
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user) // this has value
      res.redirect('/'+req.user);
});
```

If user logged in, he will redirect to example.com/his_name, but I got example.com/undefined. When I do console.log(req.user), it has value. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing `req.user` in a variable like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var currentUser = req.user;
  if(currentUser) // this has value
  res.redirect('/'+currentUser);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would help. I doubt `rec.user` changes in the less-than-a-nanosecond it takes to get from checking the `if` condition to the next line.

Comment: What do you mean? It's not supposed to change, that's the point.

Comment: Your solution only protects from `rec.user` changing between line 3 and 4 - checking the condition and executing the body of the `if`. This is such a miniscule timeframe that nothing should change, moreover, if it did change, then we have an enormous problem in our hands as anything like `if (person.age > 18) { /* proceed */}` is also bound to fail at some point. What makes you think that `rec.user` would be truthy once and only once and then set to `undefined` _immediately_ after?